# Bios changes after shut down

Tags: boot, bios

I installed an extra hard drive and my computer booted up properly. It has for 2 weeks. After I moved it to a new desk the bios changed so it would not boot from the correct drive. When I looked at the bios the drives are there but the order is wrong. I change and save but the next time wrong boot up order. We were careful moving and can not say the computer tower was jarred. 
Window 7 64
hp pavillion
amd cpu

Comment: Sounds like the CMOS battery is going bad. I would replace that and see if the changes anything. You can also switch the SATA cables which will change the boot order also.  You moving the computer likely had nothing to do with your current troubles.

Comment: Bad battery seems likely. Does the BIOS configuration change when you unplug the computer but not when you just power it off but leave it plugged in?

Answer (score 2):

To easily verify that the BIOS battery is in fact bad / degraded the best way is to simply look at the system clock - make sure that when you boot into windows you set the clock to the correct date / time, then power off completely (unplug power cable for ~30 seconds), and boot back into windows. If the date and time are now wrong, your battery is bad. The new date/ time the BIOS (the hard coded NVRAM portion portion) will default to varies, but it will be a few years off and typically 12:00 AM.

If you've already noticed that the time is frequently resetting itself than the battery is the right answer.

If it doesn't seem to be the battery after that quick test -
Are you able to boot into windows at all? i.e. does the boot order change / priority 'stick' at least once? If you are totally unable to boot into windows, then try the one time boot source selection. Right after cycling power (after the 'beep' if you have that wired up on your PC), start hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> (thats normally the key for HP), then a boot menu should appear. Select <kbd>F9</kbd> (again, typically) and select the correct hard drive to boot from. This overrides anything in the BIOS. You can than at least get into windows. At least you have a short term fix then, and if you can get back with what happened with these tests me or someone else on the site can help you some more.

I agree with the previous response that is almost certainly the battery, however I disagree with switching the SATA cables. That is a brute force change that pushes other problems down the road.

If it is not the BIOS report back with the exact part number of your pavillion. If you are running the stock OS from HP, open the HP Support Assistant software they include and the part number is at the bottom of that tool.